# Aggregation retaining in yarn-site. What does it mean, how does it work?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Let's look at https://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn

Here we have something like:

```
yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds
```

What logs are connected to this option? Hadoop DataNode? NameNode? Yarn Resource Manager?

Should I set it on all hadoop nodes? Where?

Comment: Please try to resize the problem reporting the part(s) of the article you want an help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it starts with `yarn` it only applies to YARN services.  This includes Resource Manager, Node Manager and maybe the new Timeline Server (if enabled).  YARN-specific configuration settings belong in the `yarn-site.xml`.

Similarly, 
HDFS specific configuration settings are found in the `hdfs-site.xml`.  They usually start with `dfs`.

Common settings belong to the `core-site.xml`.

You setup the `yarn-site.xml` on all hosts running YARN services.

Comment: Thank for you answer, I am newbie in this subject, so not all is clear for me. These logs are about only YARN services? Each change in yarn-site should be done on each node? And the most important: which services should be restarted after this change?

Comment: The logs only affect YARN services.  For typical clusters, Node Managers run on almost every node and are co-located with Data Nodes.  You can change the yarn-site.xml on all hosts if this simplifies things.  You will have to restart the Resource Manager and all the Node Managers.

Comment: To sum up: Everywhere where I change `yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds` I should restart NodeManager and ResourceManager (so only YARN services). Yeah?

Comment: Yes.  Only YARN services.

Comment: Is there exists information in documentation which stands that: modification of yarn-site always requires restart of all YARN services?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  But this hold true for almost all Hadoop services.  Only the YARN scheduler (which has a separate xml file) polls itself to see if there are changes to it's scheduling policy.